# Redshift AWS - Update table with lag() in sub query and cte

Tags: sql-update, subquery, amazon-redshift, common-table-expression, window-functions

I have a Redshift database with the following entries:
table name = subscribers

| time_at | calc_subscribers | calc_unsubscribers | current_subscribers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-02 07:30:00 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-07-02 07:45:00 | 39 | 8 | 0 |
| 2021-07-02 08:00:00 | 69 | 17 | 0 |
| 2021-07-02 08:15:00 | 67 | 21 | 0 |
| 2021-07-02 08:30:00 | 48 | 23 | 0 |

The goal is to calculate current_subscribers with the previous value.

```
current_subscribers = calc_subscribers - calc_unsubscribers + previous_current_subscribers
```

I do the following:

```
UPDATE subscribers sa
  SET current_subscribers = COALESCE( sa.calc_subscribers - sa.calc_unsubscribers + sub.previous_current_subscribers,0)
  FROM (
    SELECT
      time_at,
      LAG(current_subscribers, 1) OVER
      (ORDER BY time_at desc) previous_current_subscribers
      FROM subscribers
  ) sub
  WHERE sa.time_at = sub.time_at
```

The problem is that in the sub query "sub" a table is generated that is based on the current values in the table, and thus previous_current_subscribers is always 0. Instead of going through this row by row. So the result is: current_subscribers = calc_subscribers - calc_unsubscribers + 0  I have also already tried it with CTE, unfortunately without success:

The result should look like this:

| time_at | calc_subscribers | calc_unsubscribers | current_subscribers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-02 07:30:00 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-07-02 07:45:00 | 39 | 8 | 31 |
| 2021-07-02 08:00:00 | 69 | 17 | 83 |
| 2021-07-02 08:15:00 | 67 | 21 | 129 |
| 2021-07-02 08:30:00 | 48 | 95 | 82 |

I am grateful for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are running into is that you want to use the result of one row in the calculation of the current row.  This is recursive which I think you can do in this case but is expensive.

The result you are looking for is the sum of all calc_subscribers for this row and previous rows minus the sum of all calc_unsubscribers for this row and previous rows.  This is the difference between 2 window functions - sum over.

```
sum(calc_subscribers) over (order by time_at desc rows unbounded preceding) - sum(calc_unsubscribers) over (order by time_at desc rows unbounded preceding) as current_subscribers
```

Comment: Hi Bill, thanks for the quick answer. It works fine. The cost is not important in the first step, because this is executed only once on the table.

Thank you very much.